# WPF Background setting failed

Tags: wpf

Here is a code.

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/background.png",
          UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

   var backgroundBrush = new ImageBrush()
   {
    ImageSource = image,
    Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, image.PixelWidth / ActualWidth,
          image.PixelHeight / ActualHeight),
    TileMode = TileMode.Tile,
    Stretch  = Stretch.None,
   };

   // Set it for the main window.
   Background = backgroundBrush;
```

It works just fine on my PC with XPSP3 and .Net 4.0. But when I run the same sample on Eee PC T91MT with Windows 7 Home Premium it fails. No exceptions, but nothing is drawn (solid color brushes ARE drawn if used instead, though). I thought it could be the result of limited resources, but on Viliv S5, that has about the same specs it works fine too.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

The root of the problem is Viewport's rect. Since the bitmap has twice window's size by X, the rect is (0, 0, 2, 1). So, on power computer with XPSP3, the left half of the image is drawn. But on Eee PC it causes a problem with visualization.

Comment: We probably need some information about the file structure in your application to help you out.  I'm assuming that your pack Uri may have some issues.  Where is the image located in your file structure?

Comment: It's stored in app resources. It's definately being loaded, if run on another machine.

For sure, image.PixelWidth and image.PixelHeight have values 2048 and 1024, that's what the bitmap is.

Comment: I know, that's maybe too large, but why, for God's sake, it can work on one computer and cannot on another with similar guts? For instance, both have Intel Atom CPU, 1 Gb RAM, 32 Gb HDD etc. The only difference is screen size (in inches, resolution is the same, 1024*600).

Comment: P.S. image.PixelWidth and image.PixelHeight have actual values on that machine, where the problem occured. So, I guess, it has been loaded just fine, but couldn't be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just normalizing Viewport rectangle. E.g. instead of (0,0,2,1) I had to set it as (0,0,1,0.5).

I'm not sure, but it looks like WPF just transmit rect values (after some transformation) into a D3D driver, which is (or is not) able to handle it the right way. So, non-normalized rect Viewport works on GeForce-based machine but does not on Eee PC with it's integrated video's driver.